# How to execute a button from another action?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the PayPal payment form

```
<form name="form1" method="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<!-- Rest of input -->

<!-- Button that executes the redirection to paypal payment -->

<input type="submit" value="paypal sandbox">

</form>
```

But this submit type input I want to execute it from another action, I have a link outside the form (`form`) so what I want to achieve is that by clicking on the following link:

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2)">continue</a>
```

**Execute the following action:**

```
<input type="submit" value="paypal sandbox">
```

Using `jQuery` or another control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2); $('form').submit();">continue</a>
```

If you have multiple forms in the page you can identify using different selectors

- Class
- Id
- Name attribute etc

Example with form id=Myform1

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2); $('form#Myform1').submit();">continue</a>
```

Comment: But what happens if you have more forms `form` it is not more feasible to identify which form to execute.

Comment: You can use different selectors to distinguish the forms on page.. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it two way.

By submitting form:

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2); $('[name=form1]').submit();">continue</a>
```

By trigger click on `submit` button located inside it respective form:

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2); $('[type=submit]').trigger('click');">continue</a>
```